# self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; not working

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationitem

I am busy with an iPad app. I need to hide and show the leftBarButton depending on orientation, after a menu option has been selected and push segue has run.

I am fine with finding the orientation, and my code  `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;` is running according to my log, but the button doesn't hide - this only doesn't work after a segue push.

Does anyone know why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the left button to be hidden?

Comment: Hi Naleem, thanks for responding. I have tried that as well. But I create my button programmatically, it's not the back button itself.

Comment: ohh then clearly specify in your Question. anyways.. then in ViewWillAppear you can hide that button. and make [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO]; .. depends upon your requirement